# Let users log into their emails without entering the @domain.com part?

Tags: javascript, html, email, forms

I have made a page for my staff to log into their mails without the need to go to http://www.ipage.com/mail/. The page is http://www.pgla-jordan.org/staff-login.html.

here is the code for that page:

```
<form METHOD="POST" NAME="login" ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<TR>
<TD>E-mail Address:</TD>
<TD>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="credential_0" value="" SIZE="20" MAXLENGTH="128" class="formfield">
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Password:</TD>
<TD>
<INPUT TYPE="password" NAME="credential_1" SIZE="20" MAXLENGTH="50" class="formfield">
</TD>
</TR> 
<TR><TD>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="Log In" VALUE="Check Mail" onclick="javascript:login.action='https://secure.ipage.com/mailLogin';javascript:login.destination.value = '/mailadmin/index.bml?check=1';" >
</TD><TD>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="Log In" VALUE="Manage Mail" onclick="javascript:login.action='https://secure.ipage.com/mailLogin';javascript:login.destination.value = '/mailadmin/index.bml?manage=1';">
</TD></TR>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="destination">
</form>
</TABLE>
</center>
```

I want to let the users just enter the first part of their emails (the `XXXX` part in `XXXX@domain.com`) and the password to log them into their mails.

Comment: is answered to your post. is that working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do some javascript.....

```
 <INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="Log In" VALUE="Check Mail" onclick="Login()" >

 function Login()
 {
    document.getElementByName("credential_0").value =  document.getElementByName("credential_0").value + "@domain.com";

    javascript:login.action='https://secure.ipage.com/mailLogin';
    javascript:login.destination.value = '/mailadmin/index.bml?check=1';

    return true;
 }
```

hope this will work. you may have to do some fine tunes if it don't work. but logic should work for you.

Comment: thank you so much you were a great help, actually the code didnt work but it gave me a light to follow, and now after few modification it works fine, i have gave credential_0 an id=credential_0 and i used getElementById() method.. here is my final and working code :D

Comment: `code`
INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="credential_0" ID="credential_0" value="" SIZE="20" class="formfield">

<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="Log In" VALUE="Check Mail" onclick="Login()" >

 function Login()
 {
    document.getElementById("credential_0").value =  document.getElementById("credential_0").value + "@domain.com";

    javascript:login.action='https://secure.ipage.com/mailLogin';
    javascript:login.destination.value = '/mailadmin/index.bml?check=1';
    
return true;
 }

Comment: great. post this as new answer and accept your own answer. if my answer helped you give up vote. And if you need accurate answers, fiddle it from next time.